# Select variable top n from group in r

Tags: r, group-by

I know how to select a fixed top n from group in r, but how about if I want to select different number of top values from different groups? Using penguins data as example, what if I want to select the following numbers from each group?

```
top_x <- tribble(
~ species,  ~x,
"Adelie",   "10",
"Chinstrap",    "20",
"Gentoo",   "15"
)
```

then how do I pass this to top_n or is there any other way I can achieve this? basically, how to replace 10 below with different x value that matches different group name.

```
penguins %>% group_by(species) %>% top_n(10, wt = body_mass_g)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use an inequality join, where negative `body_mass_g` is ranked by group using `row_number()` (or `min_rank()` depending if you wanted ties included):

```
library(palmerpenguins)
library(dplyr)

penguins |>
  mutate(x = row_number(-body_mass_g), .by = species) |>
  right_join(top_x |>
               mutate(x = as.integer(x)), join_by(species, x$x <= y$x))


# A tibble: 45 × 10
   species island    bill_length_mm bill_depth_mm flipper_length_mm body_mass_g sex    year   x.x   x.y
   <chr>   <fct>              <dbl>         <dbl>             <int>       <int> <fct> <int> <int> <int>
 1 Adelie  Torgersen           39.2          19.6               195        4675 male   2007     4    10
 2 Adelie  Torgersen           42.5          20.7               197        4500 male   2007     8    10
 3 Adelie  Dream               39.8          19.1               184        4650 male   2007     5    10
 4 Adelie  Dream               39.6          18.8               190        4600 male   2007     6    10
 5 Adelie  Torgersen           41.8          19.4               198        4450 male   2008    10    10
 6 Adelie  Torgersen           42.9          17.6               196        4700 male   2008     3    10
 7 Adelie  Biscoe              41            20                 203        4725 male   2009     2    10
 8 Adelie  Biscoe              43.2          19                 197        4775 male   2009     1    10
 9 Adelie  Biscoe              45.6          20.3               191        4600 male   2009     7    10
10 Adelie  Dream               37.5          18.5               199        4475 male   2009     9    10
# ℹ 35 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner which uses `pmap()`:

```
purrr::pmap_dfr(top_x, \(species, x) penguins[penguins$species == species,] |> slice_max(n = as.integer(x), order_by = body_mass_g, with_ties = FALSE))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 45 × 8
   species island    bill_length_mm bill_depth_mm flipper_length_mm body_mass_g
   <fct>   <fct>              <dbl>         <dbl>             <int>       <int>
 1 Adelie  Biscoe              43.2          19                 197        4775
 2 Adelie  Biscoe              41            20                 203        4725
 3 Adelie  Torgersen           42.9          17.6               196        4700
 4 Adelie  Torgersen           39.2          19.6               195        4675
 5 Adelie  Dream               39.8          19.1               184        4650
 6 Adelie  Dream               39.6          18.8               190        4600
 7 Adelie  Biscoe              45.6          20.3               191        4600
 8 Adelie  Torgersen           42.5          20.7               197        4500
 9 Adelie  Dream               37.5          18.5               199        4475
10 Adelie  Torgersen           41.8          19.4               198        4450
# ℹ 35 more rows
# ℹ 2 more variables: sex <fct>, year <int>
```

Comment: sorry I've been writing to you so often lately my work group wants us to hand in the manuscript before wheinachten and the person who coded everything moved away so I had to step in at short notice without much idea! Can you help me with the question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77665223/change-ticks-on-collorbar-manually

Comment: I'm happy to help @Weiss, but every time you post a comment, someone has already helped you!

Comment: Hi @Mark I feel so sorry for that, often I Wait halfe a day, than I contact you, but then I got an answer from someone else! I feel every Time very sorry for This! However, I still want to thank you every time, even if someone else has answered! It's great to know that there are people like you out there! If you celebrate Christmas I wish you a Merry Christmas, if you don't I wish you a wonderful time!

Comment: it's all good. Ye of little faith in the power of Stack Overflow  Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

An approach using `filter` by `row_number` taken from *top_x*

Note: Replacing the characters in *top_x$x* with integers.

```
library(tibble)

top_x <- tribble(
~ species,  ~x,
"Adelie",   4,
"Chinstrap",    3,
"Gentoo",   5
)
```

```
library(dplyr)

penguins %>% 
  arrange(species, desc(body_mass_g)) %>% 
  filter(row_number() <= top_x$x[top_x$species %in% species][1], .by=species)
# A tibble: 12 × 7
   species island culmen_length_mm culmen_depth_mm flipper_length_mm body_mass_g
   <chr>   <chr>             <dbl>           <dbl>             <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 Adelie  Biscoe             43.2            19                 197        4775
 2 Adelie  Biscoe             41              20                 203        4725
 3 Adelie  Torge…             42.9            17.6               196        4700
 4 Adelie  Torge…             39.2            19.6               195        4675
 5 Chinst… Dream              52              20.7               210        4800
 6 Chinst… Dream              52.8            20                 205        4550
 7 Chinst… Dream              53.5            19.9               205        4500
 8 Gentoo  Biscoe             49.2            15.2               221        6300
 9 Gentoo  Biscoe             59.6            17                 230        6050
10 Gentoo  Biscoe             51.1            16.3               220        6000
11 Gentoo  Biscoe             48.8            16.2               222        6000
12 Gentoo  Biscoe             45.2            16.4               223        5950
# ℹ 1 more variable: sex <chr>
```