# Change Ticks on Collorbar (manually)

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I would like to display Change cards. I have this database (ChangeEU)

```
        Latitude  Longitude  Altitude     Value      O18d
0           30.0      -30.0       0.0  1.262094  1.262094
1           30.0      -29.9       0.0  1.269815  1.269815
2           30.0      -29.8       0.0  1.277522  1.277522
3           30.0      -29.7       0.0  1.285215  1.285215
4           30.0      -29.6       0.0  1.292893  1.292893
...          ...        ...       ...       ...       ...
359995      69.9       59.5      68.0 -1.237269 -1.373269
359996      69.9       59.6      74.0 -1.235324 -1.383324
359997      69.9       59.7      52.0 -1.233395 -1.337395
359998      69.9       59.8      71.0 -1.231478 -1.373478
359999      69.9       59.9      68.0 -1.229575 -1.365575
```

And I display it with this code

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import basemap
from scipy.stats import norm
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from scipy.stats import norm
from matplotlib import colors
from matplotlib.patches import Path, PathPatch
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
import pandas as pd
from Data_Prep_Paper import *

def load_ChangeEU():
    ChangeEU = dflediffan
    return ChangeEU


def base_data(ChangeEU):
    return{
        'late':np.array(ChangeEU['Latitude']),
        'lone':np.array(ChangeEU['Longitude']),
        'vale':np.array(ChangeEU['O18d']),

    } 

def plot_Diff(data):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))

    ax =fig.add_subplot(221)
    ax.set_title("Annual Change EU PRÜFEN OB DATEN DIE RICHTIGEN SIND", fontsize = 10)
    m = basemap.Basemap(llcrnrlon=-30, llcrnrlat=30,urcrnrlon=60,urcrnrlat=70, resolution='l',area_thresh=1000)
    m.drawcoastlines(color = 'black')
    x,y = m(data['lone'],data['late'])
    divnorm=colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=-8., vcenter=0., vmax=3)
    m.contourf(x,y,data['vale'],32, tri=True,norm=divnorm, cmap = 'PuBu_r')
    plt.colorbar(location='bottom',pad=0.04,fraction=0.08)
    x0,x1 = ax.get_xlim()
    y0,y1 = ax.get_ylim()
    map_edges = np.array([[x0,y0],[x1,y0],[x1,y1],[x0,y1]])
    polys = [p.boundary for p in m.landpolygons]
    polys = [map_edges]+polys[:]
    codes = [
        [Path.MOVETO]+[Path.LINETO for p in p[1:]]
        for p in polys
    ]
    polys_lin = [v for p in polys for v in p]
    codes_lin = [xx for cs in codes for xx in cs]
    path = Path(polys_lin, codes_lin)
    patch = PathPatch(path,facecolor='white', lw=0)
    ax.add_patch(patch)

    
ChangeEU = load_ChangeEU()
base_data = base_data(ChangeEU) 
plot_Diff(base_data)
plt.show()
```

The output is this:

[image]

As you can see, the colour bar is labelled with decimal numbers. However, I would like the dark blue in the colour bar to be -10 and the red end to be 2. How can I set this manually without changing the colour scale?  I have already tried using ticks but that didn't change the result and manuel.ticks didn't work for me either.

What I like to have:

[image]

Comment: Does this make a difference: `c = m.contourf(...)` then `plt.colorbar(mappable=c, ...)`

Comment: @user3128 I found my previous error, I used an Colorbar which didn´t have Red ....s sorry but now I do have a differend error

Comment: @user3128 I think this is a simmelar problem as u solved it in my last question or?

Comment: Does it help if you do `m.contourf(..., vmin=-10, vmax=4)`

Comment: not it shows the same :c

Comment: @user3128 Sorry for annoying so much, but I have to submitt the maps in a few days :e can you have another look?

Comment: Sure. I will try to replicate the problem.

Comment: The colormap I finaly used is RdBu_r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work in terms of setting the limits of the colour bar. Not sure if it respects the original scale that you requested.

We make a `ScalarMappable` that maps data values to a colour. It does the mapping based on the `norm=` you give it and the colourmap specified. The limits are determined by the object supplied to `norm=` (`divnorm` in this case),

[image]

Replace these lines in `plot_Diff()`:

```
divnorm=colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=-8., vcenter=0., vmax=3)
m.contourf(x,y,data['vale'],32, tri=True,norm=divnorm, cmap = 'PuBu_r')
plt.colorbar(location='bottom',pad=0.04,fraction=0.08)
```

with

```
 from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable

 divnorm = colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=-10, vcenter=0., vmax=4)
 scalar_mapper = ScalarMappable(norm=divnorm, cmap='RdBu_r')

 m.contourf(x, y, data['vale'], 32, tri=True)

 fig.colorbar(mappable=scalar_mapper, location='bottom',
              pad=0.04, fraction=0.08, label='colorbar')
```

---

**Update** This part is about how I created a new colour map that goes from dark blue to a light shade of red.

[image]

I sampled the 0-0.8 range from the original colour map, and wrapped those rgb values in a new colourmap object.

Replace these lines

```
    divnorm=colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=-8., vcenter=0., vmax=3)
    m.contourf(x,y,data['vale'],32, tri=True,norm=divnorm, cmap = 'PuBu_r')
    plt.colorbar(location='bottom',pad=0.04,fraction=0.08)
```

with

```
    from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
    colormap_resolution = 35
    red_intensity = 0.75
    darkBu_to_lightRd_rgb = plt.cm.RdBu_r(
        np.linspace(0, red_intensity, num=colormap_resolution)
    )
    cmap_darkBu_lightRd = colors.ListedColormap(darkBu_to_lightRd_rgb)
    cmap_darkBu_lightRd
    
    divnorm = colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=-10, vcenter=0., vmax=2)
    scalar_mapper = ScalarMappable(norm=divnorm, cmap=cmap_darkBu_lightRd)

    m.contourf(x, y, data['vale'], 32, tri=True)

    cb= fig.colorbar(
        mappable=scalar_mapper, location='bottom',
        pad=0.04, fraction=0.08, label='colorbar title',
        ticks=[-10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 1, 2]
    )
```

To make the red shade more intense, increase `red_intensity=0.75` towards `1.0`. To make the colour map smoother, increase `colormap_resolution=35` to a larger number.

Comment: Nice thank you! However the red u See in my figure should be the Maximum on the map and scale.

Comment: The figure you posted has a light shade of red at 1.6. The colour bar I showed goes up to a dark red at 4. Do you want the colour bar to only go up to light red at 4? If it's a light red at 4, then 1.6 & the map could become very close to white? If you're able to provide a sketch of the colour bar that would help.

Comment: Sorry for my delay! I updated my question :) hope this helpes

Comment: Thanks. I've added an update to my answer.

Comment: Okay thank you so much, however I do have another request I hope this is fine? So vcenter=0 have to be at the white spot so i can display the change

Comment: Changing the code to `vcenter=-1` makes it look like 0 is at white.

Comment: okay thank you so much!!

Comment: No worries @Weiss, glad to have helped.